# Send a variable from the controller to the form

Tags: php, symfony

```
 $objSearchForm = $this->createForm('uts_hotel_search_request', $objSearchRequest);/*создаем форму с запросом*/
    $templateVars = array(
        'searchForm' => $objSearchForm->createView(),
        'request' => $objSearchRequest
    );
    if($objSearchRequest->isComplete() || $objSearchRequest->isOld()){
        $repository = $em->getRepository('UtsHotelBundle:SearchResult');
        $query = $repository->createQueryForPagination($searchId);/* создаем запрос*/
        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');/**/
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate($query, $page, 50);    
 $templateVars['pagination'] = $pagination;
 $templateVars['count'] = $req;
 $templateVars['hotels'] = $req;
 return $this->render('UtsHotelBundle:Default:results.html.twig', $templateVars);
```

In view:

`{{  templateVars['count'] }}`

But I got error:

> Variable "templateVars" does not exist in
>   UtsHotelBundle:Default:results.html.twig

Comment: Can you provide some more information. I am not sure if you can render $templateVars like that. maybe ..., array( 'templatevars'  => $templateVars) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$templateVars` will be extracted so you can access like:

```
{{ count }}
{{ pagination }}
```

or you can change it to:

```
return $this->render(
    'UtsHotelBundle:Default:results.html.twig',
    ['templateVars' => $templateVars]
);
```

then your be able to access it like

```
{{ templateVars['count'] }}
```

Comment: If I change it, then got error "Variable "searchForm" does not exist in"

Comment: @randomUser what did you change? `searchForm` is not in your question.